# Save an Image to hard disk using HTML 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I save a captured image using my webcam to any folder on my hard disk using javascript and HTML5.
Please note that I use the following code:

```
function snapshot() {
    if (localMediaStream) {
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
}
```

I Just need to save the Image.

Comment: http://creative-jar.com/insights/labs/digital-technology/how-to-take-a-photo-with-html5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has a lot of info on your topic:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

The getUserMedia API is what you want to be looking at.